# How to define a static class variable in Object-C?

Tags: objective-c

i an new in Object-C. i want to know how to define a static class variable. i code this based on one book:

```
static int count = 0; // staic class variable
@interface ClassA : NSObject{
}

+(int) initCount;
+(void) initialize;
@end

@implementation ClassA

-(id) init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        count++;
    }
    return self;
}

+(int) initCount{
    return count;
}

+(void) initialize{
    count = 0;
}
@end
```

you know, the variable `count` not in ClassA, could i define the staic class variable like C++?
in C++, we can define like this:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject{
static int count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did looks good, but you should declare the static variable in the implementation (`.m` file).

So you will have something like:

```
@interface ClassA:NSObject 
+(int) initCount;
@end
// ClassA.m
static int count = 0;
@implementation
+(int) initCount{
  return count;
}
@end
```

Objective-C doesn't have "class variables", but doing it like this you create a pseudo class variable.

Comment: @BlackMamba: It would be really nice if you started to "accept" helpful answers. Just click on the check mark!

Comment: @MartinR I cann't find the `the check mark` is this page? Could you tell me ?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! i habe done it.